# Moving Table Data in a Table Structure Up

Tags: html-table, tr

[image]

```
<tr>
    <th>Photo</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/square.png" alt="box" width="70px" />
    </td>

    <td class="description">The Rhodes piano is an electro-mechanical piano, 
    invented by Harold Rhodes during the fifties and later manufactured in a number
     of models, first in collaboration with Fender and after 1965 by CBS. It employs
      a piano-like keyboard with hammers that hit small metal tines, amplified by 
      electromagnetic pickups. 
    </td>

      <td id="price">$1400</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I am trying to achieve here is for the $1400 price range to line up with the first line of text in the paragraph. I will have two more of these tables that look exactly the same. I have learned that when entering table data; the data will be in the center of the box. What I think works is giving the price range a class and moving them up using padding-bottom by 55px. I was jsut wondering if there was a better way to move up the price range?
[image: FlexBox Code]

[image: newcode]

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a table, this seems like a perfect option for flexbox, which is kind of the modern solution to this. Otherwise, in CSS for your table for the element use `vertical-align:top`

Comment: I added a new image in the posting above of my flexbox code would you consider this messy code? Still new to programming. If there is a simpler way to define the rules, attributes and elements please let me know.

Comment: try this link out it describes exactly what you want and provides clear code examples for turning HTML Tables into Flexbox tables, and it also shows how to align content the correct way: https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/ if you still have troubles with this, I will write out a solution both for tables and Flexbox when I get back home (on vacation for New Years)... here is a codepen for content-alignment solutions: https://codepen.io/davidelrizzo/pen/PZMYWw?editors=0100

Comment: Hey, thanks for the links. I think I have an idea of how it works. I've added a second image above. This seemed to be more simplified. What do you think? Also in this particular situation of using a flexbox, is it even word adding min-width and max-height?